Obtain Guest User IP Address from Prior Visits to Experience Site
Is there a way to obtain the IP address of a prior Guest User visit to an Experience Cloud site?
I have seen some questions here addressing the need for setting up a process to obtain the IP address of new visits to an Experience Cloud site, however, what I'm looking for is to obtain an IP address of a visit that already happened a few days or weeks ago. We did not specifically set up anything already, or have anything in our org specifically designed to track this. I am not sure if this is something that Salesforce allows out of the box or would only be possible if I had set up something specifically for this purpose beforehand.
I'm inclined to believe it isn't possible, but I would love to be proven wrong.

Google Analytics is your friend. Extra credit: guest UVID

Thanks for the tips, I'll look into those moving forward
